# Не отрабатывает скрипт помещённый в автозагрузку

Tags: python

Сложилась следующая ситуация: имеется рабочий скрипт, он запускается, делает свои дела, потом по условию запускает дочерний процесс через os.system и завершается. Этот скрипт был откомпилирован через pyinstaller в .exe и отлично работал по двойному клику на любой машине. Возникла необходимость сделать так чтобы этот .exe стартовал при входе пользователя в систему.

И начались проблемы: при входе пользователя в систему скрипт запускается но, не запускает дочерний процесс и просто закрывается. Пробовал добавлять в автозагрузку и через реестр, и через планировщик. Результат одинаковый. Может кто-то знает что ему мешает?

Comment: Например, скрипт может пытаться обращаться к какому-то файлу по относительному пути от рабочей директории, а это не всегда директория, где скрипт лежит. Нужно определять фактическую директорию скрипта, от нее определять пути к файлам.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Полный путь к вызываемому скрипту решил проблему.